# Disappearing missions in Dragon Age Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

As players of this game series know, your actions in one place can have an impact on many other parts of the game.

One place where this becomes a problem is in completing side quests. I know it has happened in past dragon age games where if you advance the plot past a certain point, you lose the ability to do certain side quests (if you have not already done them).

I read somewhere (very unofficial) that this should be less of a concern in Inquisition, but now I am questioning that. There are a couple missions I think I missed out on and I am wondering if anybody can verify this, or maybe I am just going insane?

While I was in Haven, there were war table missions for "hard in hightown" in kirkwall. And once I completed it I swear I was given the choice of traveling to it (like when you first unlock an area, you will get a "quick" option to travel there immediately). I figured I would come back to it later since I was still very early in the game. Get to skyhold and that area is no longer there!

This also happened again with a similar mission after skyhold. Now I have completed the final hard in hightown mission on the board (there are multiple missions available over time), but this last one does not involve traveling.

I just seem to remember so clearly I had the option to travel to hightown while I was in Haven and I remember being very excited to see how it looked between the games... Now I am starting to think I was crazy, but that is a lot of detail for my mind to make up...

Is there a "hard in hightown" mission early in the game where you travel? Or no?

Comment: I suspect I will be answering my own question when I get around to my second playthrough.... :/

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I never saw a hard in hightown mission on my map before getting to Skyhold.

Comment: 'Hard in Hightown' does not unlock a travelable location. It just stays on the map because it's a companion mission.

Answer (score 1):

The side quest don't disappear I was wondering the same thing you were so I made a separate save and went ahead in the story missions and none of my side quests went away. But make sure to check around haven or skyhold when doing this as those quests will disappear for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I beat the game and I had two companion quests left over.  They disappeared and the companions and advisers started to act like Kasumi and Zaeed from Mass Effect 2 once I beat the game.  Some quests do seem to disappear, but those are the only ones that I know of.  This game is so big that maybe only a hand full of side quests will disappear and we won't notice.

Answer (score 1):

I had one side quest disappear--it was mission to task a young templar and his companion, a mage, who were friends of Cole and were rescued by the Inquisition.

I didn't do the mission right away and it just disappeared from the War Table.

So yes, it does happen sometimes. Irritating.